# Elementary way to prove that the radical of a principal ideal in a UFD has a certain form

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a UFD and $x \in R$. Then we can write $x = x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n ^ {\alpha_n}$ with $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ irreducible. To see that $\sqrt{(x)} = (x_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n)$:

- $\supseteq$ is obtained by raising $x_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n$ to the maximum of all $\alpha_i$'s.
- $\subseteq$: for this, I could only think of using that $(x_1), \ldots, (x_n)$ are all prime ideals that sit over $(x)$ and the fact that in general $\sqrt I = \bigcap\limits_{\substack{\mathfrak{p} \in spec(R) \\ I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}} } \mathfrak{p}$. But the latter fact has a rather involved proof and it seems like it wouldn't be needed for such a simple statement.

My question is, can "$\subseteq$" be proved more elementarily? How? I don't know where to go from just writing $y ^ l = z x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n^{\alpha_n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\,k\ge1\,$ then $\,x_i\mid x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}\mid y^k\,\Rightarrow\, x_i\mid y\,\Rightarrow\, x_1\cdots x_n\mid y,\,$ by $\,x_i\,$ nonassociate primes.